# Add cookie to SocketIoClientDotNet

Tags: javascript, c#, cookies, windows-runtime, socket.io

I am developing Windows 8.1 WinRT app and I would like to connect with Node.JS server on socket. Server on socket connection event read field `socket.handshake.headers.cookie`, because web browser can write user login in cookie but how I can write it by SocketIoClientDotNet? Is there any way to add a header with cookie to IO.Socket object?